# Code Processing (Client Side instead of on Server)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe, client-side

I want generate a development tool that I can input code (Such as HTML, CSS and JS) and it will create a preview/result window (like JSFiddle). I will be using it for tutorials in school and need a unique site to do this from (I would love to use CodePen, JS Fiddle or Codecademy... But I can't).

I am able to generate a form that can be processed and shown in an iframe (through PHP where it simply echos the information into a new html file that is shown in the iframe). But this came with problems; I only have a cheap server and won't want to put too much pressure on it so need todo this through JS/jQuery.

Firstly is this possible? And how would I go about doing it (code examples would be great!)?

Thanks in advance (I appologise if I haven't given enough detail but I'm fairly new to this and may just be asking a pointless question (I'm only 15 :/ ) )

Cheers  :)

Comment: if you want something that just shows rendered html,css,js (client-side only) then you can use pretty much any of the popular code-focused text editors out there, e.g. notepad++ or html-kit.  If you want something that will parse server-side stuff like php, you can install something like wamp or xampp. IOW you do all this locally without having to reinvent the wheel with your own tool

Comment: You would have to have a painfully underpowered server to not echo text into a page. A Raspberry Pi ($35 computer) could serve that up easily.

Comment: IOW your webpage doesn't have to be hosted on some other server. Your browser will render a page just fine with the file(s) on your own computer. If it's purely client-side stuff, just rightlick the file and open with browser. If you want to stuff like parse php then you will need to install a server on your computer (like i said easiest is to just install wamp or xampp)

Comment: Hi @CrayonViolent I am looking to make a webpage ideally as it needs to be accessed on things like iPads with the tutorials I will make on screen so can't really go through third party apps TBH.

Comment: @JasonSperske the problem I had was people putting in endless loops with PHP so would need something that would crash the browser and not the server :)

Comment: I misunderstood, you want client side execution of PHP? That is a much harder problem.

Comment: @JasonSperske That, or a Javascript / jQuery alternative that would have the same outcome as the PHP script that echos the code. Thanks for your help btw :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a rather impressive project called [php.js](http://phpjs.hertzen.com/) that will let you parse and execute a subset of PHP code in the browser.

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I was looking for and I didn't even know it exists :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it complete on a client/ in browser like jsfiddel do, then you need 2 or more frames.
One is for your code and one is for the output.

If you click on "run", then need to apply your code to the frame. You can do this by accessing the `document` object of the frame. If you got it, you´ll need to inject your code there. There many examples in the web on how to access a child `document` object from an frame/iframe.